# Kubernetes: stop container when application finishes

Tags: kubernetes

I added a container to an existing service deployment yaml in kubernetes. It's a simple Java app that does some task and finishes.

I observe that once the app finishes it comes back and starts doing task again.

I want it to execute only once.

How do we achieve that?

Comment: Maybe run a job that connects to this app: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/?

Comment: can you try by giving a `restart policy: Never` in your job yaml if this is not working then try giving `backoffLimit: 0`  if one wants a job to never retry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the `K8s Job` instead of the `K8s Deployment`. In the job, once the task is completed, the pods are not automatically restarted.

**Sample Job Yaml (sample-job.yaml):**

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: job-name
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: container-name
        image: your-image
        command: ["java", "-jar", "your-app.jar"]
      restartPolicy: Never
```

Apply it:  `kubectl apply -f sample-job.yaml`. It will create the Job, and it will execute your Java application only once.

`kind` is set to Job. `restartPolicy` is set to `Never`, indicating that the pods should not be restarted once they have completed their task.

**Job details:** https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/